# Shortcut not working

Tags: release-loki, slingshot, app-shortcuts

I'm on elementary 0.4.1 Loki and I run Telegram Desktop. The only way I can get the special characters such as `é` or `ã` on Telegram Desktop is to run with this command:

```
QT_IM_MODULE=xim Downloads/Telegram/Telegram
```

So I made a shortcut for starting telegram with special characters, but it just doesn't work. Other shortcuts work fine but this one wont start. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to put the whole code here.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Telegram Desktop
Comment=Official desktop version of Telegram messaging app
Exec=env QT_IM_MODULE=xim /opt/Telegram/Telegram -- %u
Icon=telegram
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass=TelegramDesktop
Type=Application
Categories=Network;InstantMessaging;Qt;
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/tg;
X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.22
```

But you need to delete the `TryExec` line, otherwise it will not open.

But this is a palliative. Other applications running on QT will need extra settings. Try to do the following:

```
setxkbmap -model abnt2 -layout br -variant abnt2
```

And:

```
sudo printf 'XKBMODEL="pc105"\nXKBLAYOUT="br"\nXKBVARIANT="abnt2"\nXKBOPTIONS=""' > /etc/default/keyboard
```

And reboot. This should resolve permanently. Then tell me if that solved it.